# useState value changes when i call it from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating a timer app built using react-hooks and an array of this timers
I don't understand why timerList changes

Here it is the parent component

```
const [timerList, setTimerList] = useState([]);


const removeTimer = () => {
  console.log("timerList", timerList);
};

return (
    <div id="main">
      {timerList ? timerList.map((child) => child) : null}
      <div className="add-button before">
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            const time = new Date();
            time.setSeconds(time.getSeconds() + 0);
            setTimerList((timerList) => [
              ...timerList,
              <FullTimer
                expiryTimestamp={time}
                removeTimer={() => {
                  removeTimer();
                }}
                id={window.prompt("Insert timer name") + ` ${timerList.length}`}
                key={timerList.length}
              />,
            ]);
          }}
        >
```

The interested child's component part:

```
<button
  onClick={() => {
     removeTimer();
  }}
>
```

The child component is a custom timer with some css, and when i call removeTimer the value of timerList (in the parent component) changes, when it should remain the same.

What am I missing?

P.S. the button tags aren't closed because i have some  element inside them that use awesome-font

Comment: is there any case that you misclick on the parent button and then click on the child component?

Comment: No, because when i click parent button a new FullTimer is created (i see it visually and with react dev tools) @PhạmHuyPhát

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Side note*: In general it's considered bad practice to store components in another components state.

---

But that's not really the problem here. Given your code, it's a [simple closure problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).

This:

```
const removeTimer = () => {
  console.log("timerList", timerList);
};
```

definition *closes over* the current `timerList`. So it will *log* it, as it was when `removeTimer` was assigned. Currently that's on every render. So it will log the state seemingly *one step behind*. There's no fix around that, because that's just how closures work.

Provided you actually want to remove a timer, when `removeTimer` is invoked, you would need to use the callback version of the updater (`setTimerList`) and pass some identifying value so that you can actually remove the correct one.

This would all be a lot simpler, if you followed the initial advice and don't store the component in the state, but rather it's defining properties.

---

The following would be a working example (please excuse my typescript):

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

type FullTimerProps = {
  id: string;
  expiryTimestamp: Date;
  removeTimer: () => void;
}

const FullTimer = ({expiryTimestamp, removeTimer, id}: FullTimerProps): JSX.Element => {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={removeTimer}>remove</button>
      {id}: {expiryTimestamp.toLocaleDateString()}
    </div>
  );
};

type Timer = {
  id: string;
  expiryTimestamp: Date;
};

const TimerList = (): JSX.Element => {
  const [timerList, setTimerList] = useState<Timer[]>([]);

  const removeTimer = (timer: Timer) => {
    setTimerList(timerList => timerList.filter(t => t.id !== timer.id));
  };

  return (
    <div id="main">
      {timerList.map(timer => (
        <FullTimer
          key={timer.id}
          id={timer.id}
          expiryTimestamp={timer.expiryTimestamp}
          removeTimer={() => removeTimer(timer)}
        />
      ))}

      <div className="add-button before">
        <button
          onClick={() =>
            setTimerList(timerList => [...timerList, {
              id: window.prompt('Insert timer name') + ` ${timerList.length}`,
              expiryTimestamp: new Date()
            }])}
        >Add
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

changing this code snippet

```
            setTimerList((timerList) => [
              ...timerList,
              <FullTimer
                expiryTimestamp={time}
                removeTimer={() => removeTimer()}
                id={window.prompt("Insert timer name") + ` ${timerList.length}`}
                key={timerList.length}
              />,
            ]);
```

to

```
            timerList.push(<FullTimer
              expiryTimestamp={time}
              removeTimer={() => removeTimer()}
              id={window.prompt("Insert timer name") + ` ${timerList.length}`}
              key={timerList.length}
            />);
            setTimerList([...timerList]);
```

Fixed the problem you are having. Although this change is not recommended because it is not immutable approach, but it fixes this case.

UPDATE: It turned out that you duplicated the removeTimer function during the `setTimerList` call which cause the child component to capture the `timerList` at the moment of assignment. Which is mentioned at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures?retiredLocale=vi#closure as mr @yoshi has shown

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your onclick function like this

```
<button
  onClick={() => removeTimer()}
>
```

Also over here

```
 <FullTimer
    expiryTimestamp={time}
    removeTimer={() => removeTimer()}
```

Comment: same behaviour. When i click the button in a component timerLIst is seen as the original list without the next components (included the component's button).
Ex: if i click the button in the first component, timerLIst === []
second component timerList === [ {...} ] and go on...

Comment: Is it possible to add a stackblitz code so that it will better for us to understand ur problem

Comment: [link to stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jybhsx?file=src/App.js) 
Idk if i missed something because it's the first time i use it

Comment: I was expecting a workable code where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: I really don't know why it isn't working.
here it is the [github repo](https://github.com/ginop-1/react-timer-app) with all the files, if it helps.

Comment: @Gino_P interesting case, I am checking it rightnow using your github repo